# Will my SSL certificate work for new Wordpress website on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, ssl, iis, https

I have an IIS running on the server and a website (.net) running perfectly on http (80) and https (443). And i have a new Wordpress website. I wanna publish the wordpress site on the same domain. In order to do it i will remove the files of the present website and place the new site's files and in theory,i expect IIS will start to show this new site. And all the bindings and everything s set on IIS for this SSL certificate for the same domain. So my question is , can i expect that new site will run perfectly on http (80) and https (443)? Or will https fail?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in theory it should work but as you know with IIS, what is true in theory may not always be true in practice.

What you will find tricky is that Wordpress is heavily reliant on URLs and it may be tricky to run both options, ideally you should force one or the other but there are techniques that allow you to run both.

I can't speak for the effectivity or efficiency of this but here's a link: https://blog.rabin.io/sysadmin/make-wordpress-site-work-both-http-https

Comment: Thx Daniel. As i expected my theory failed ) I moved the site yesterday, so far http is working but https requests end up with  "Your connection is not secure" message. I double checked the IIS and all the bindings and settings looked right to me. I am a bit puzzled. Any suggestions?

Comment: LOL - I know those struggles. You may find that some of the content is still being delivered via http when you're browsing the https version and so the mixed content on the page will trigger that warning. Why not just force https all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Well in theory it supposed to work but it didn t. Eventually  i figured that SSL certificate was revoked.